# How to create to HoloEverywhere SliderMenu with more than one activity in it?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

i am using `holoeverywhere` + `ABS` + `ViewPager`. I have an activity(`mainactivity`) with 3 actionbar tabs(fragments) in it and i need to implement slider addon from [holoeverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) to my project which switches between mainactivity(which has tabs in it) and a second activity. I tried to reverse engineer from demo app but i noticed that they use one activity with fragments in it(all slider items are fragments and not activities). I don't know how i can setup slidermenu with two activities.

Here is my activitiy's onCreate():

```
tabs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
pager = ((CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager));
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
adapterViewPager = new AdapterViewPager(getSupportFragmentManager(),
        tabs);
pager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

PS: can i use slidingmenu project with holoeverywhere? is yours better regarding compatibility with holoeverywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SliderMenu addon support only fragments.
But SliderMenu - only pre-built control view over Slider addon.
You can make /anything/ with /any/ view in /any/ hierarchy.
Just create your custom layout and place it in left (right) panel and provide control logic for it.